# django skip a field's validation

Tags: django, django-validation

I need to skip validation of the OrderAmount field but for it to still save the invalidated data. Is there a way this can be done? I know django allows you to make your own validation, but I don't know how to make it completely skip just one field's validation.

model:

```
class LiquorOrder(models.Model):

    pack_size = (
                ('1', '1'),
                ('2', '2'),
            )

    LiquorOrderID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    storeliquorID = models.ForeignKey(StoreLiquor)
    orderID = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    OrderAmount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Order Amount', max_length=3, choices=pack_size)
    TotalPrice = models.DecimalField('Total Price', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

Form:

```
class AddToOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = LiquorOrder
        fields = ('OrderAmount',)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a [PositiveSmallIntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#positivesmallintegerfield) the only validation Django does is ensure the value is indeed a positive integer within the appropriate range.  If you were to skip this, you would run into problems when Django tries to write the value to your database.  If you were to, say, try to write the value "marshmallows" to a DB column that's expecting an integer, the DB will throw errors and Django will turn around and throw you an [IntegrityError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/exceptions/#django.db.IntegrityError).

If you really wanted to try, you could override the field to be [CharField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/fields/#charfield) with required set to `False` (basically allowing any keyboard input):

```
class AddToOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    OrderAmount = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

Django would then return `True` when you run `is_valid()`, but throw errors when you try to call `save()`.

---

It sounds like your real issue is with your model not matching your current project requirements.  If that is the case, look into migrating to a new model.  The Python library *[South](http://south.aeracode.org/)* is brilliant tool for this purpose and is used heavily by the Django community.  I would read up on DB migrations and see if you can come up with a solution that way.